# OVI Map Route API Over HTTP

Tags: dictionary, nokia, distance, routes, ovi

I'm doing some research on route distance calculation APIs, and I came across this API from Ovi/Nokia: http://api.maps.ovi.com/devguide/getting_started.html#Services

Does anyone know if they have an equivalent REST API that can be used outside of a client browser scenario?

If not, what's the best option for route distance calculation APIs? I've looked into Google, Bing, and MapQuest, but I would like to be able to use it internally without a daily rate limit.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [maps image API](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Maps/Map_Image_API/), if showing the routes as images are sufficient. This page has the complete list if [Nokia Maps APIs](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Maps/).

Comment: I'm actually just looking to send two addresses and get back a distance between them. I don't need to show images or do anything visual. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to repeat what is done, so please refer to the Nokia API reference, but to be more accurate use distance method from nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate. The complete documentation is here 
Click [here](https://api.maps.nokia.com/en/apireference/2.2.0/symbols/nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate.html?s=distance#distance)!